# Angular.dart + polymer.dart to js?

Tags: angularjs, dart, angular-dart

Can I develop an app in Angular.dart + Polymer.dart and translate it to JS code? because as far I know, browsers cannot understand dart language yet.

I know there is a dart2js tool, but I don't know if it supports angular framework.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can translate Angular.dart and Polymer.dart apps to JavaScript to run them in modern browsers (Chrome, FireFox, Safari, Opera, mobile)
but as far as I know there are still some issues when using Angular.dart and with Polymer.dart together (when binding attributes/event handlers from one to the other).

Comment: It is better to use angular.js and polymer.js?

Comment: I don't understand this comment. This question/answer is about Angular.dart and Polymer.dart. These are compiled to plain JS not to Angular.js or Polymer.js. What do you want to do or to build? What problem do you have?

Comment: I want to start write frontend webapplication and angular.js provide more tools than angular.dart. The community of angular.js is much bigger then angular.dart. But otherwise I want to use the advantages of dart, for example debugging is awesome. My question is, what should it choose angular dart or js version?

Comment: Ok, this question is more clear :-) I like Angular.dart a lot (I have no experience with Angular.js) but currently the future of Angular.dart is IMHO unclear. I wouldn't suggest using Angular.dart until the future development is more clear. I can suggest Polymer.dart without hesitation though.

Comment: When will we get to know about the future of angular.dart and dart.

Comment: I haven't seen much detailed information about future plans. You can take a look at this discussion https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular-dart/p8qmDQUtaso. I guess this will not be settled in the near future.

Comment: Everything seems to be delay. Google have to decide, which way they will go.

Comment: What do you mean by "everything"?

Comment: I mean angular.dart, angular.js, polymer.dart or polymer.js

Comment: I see this only for Angular.dart currently. Angular.js, Polymer.js and Polymer.dart make good progress and at least for me there are no doubts they can be recommended. Polymer.js went from experimental to beta yesterday. Polymer.dart is always slightly behind because it builds on `Polymer.js`. Angular.dart is 1.0 but at the same time they announced a totally different approach for further development which just brings up a lot of doubts.